# Interesting loops and booleans

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, boolean, nested-loops

I am coding for my programing class which is supposed to be made to read and fine if in a 2 layer multidimensional array has 4 equal values in a row in either a diagonal, vertical, or horizontal fashion. Here is my code.

```
public static boolean isConseccutiveFour (int[][] matrix){
    //creates a boolean to give answer later on
    boolean connection = true;
    int[][] consecFour = matrix;
    //incrementing for loops that move through the two arrays by going horizontally then diagonally
    for (int Y = 0; Y < consecFour.length - 3; Y++){
        for(int X= 0; X < consecFour[0].length - 3; X++){
            //if statement used to give the proper constraints for diagonal check 
            if ((consecFour.length - Y < 3) && (consecFour[0].length - X < 3)){
                if ( consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X + 1][Y + 1] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X+2][Y+2] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X+3][Y+3])
                    connection = true;
            }
            //if statement used to give the proper constraints for diagonal check 
            else if ((consecFour.length - Y < 3) && (consecFour[0].length < 3)){
                if ( consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X-1][Y-1] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X-2][Y-2] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X-3][Y-3])
                    connection = true;
            }
            //if statement used to give the proper constraints for horizontal check 
            else if (consecFour[0].length - X < 3){
                if(consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X+1][Y] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X+2][Y] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X+3][Y])
                    connection = true;
            }
            //if statement used to give the proper constraints for vertical check 
            else if (consecFour.length - Y < 3){
                if ( consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X][Y + 1] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X][Y+2] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X][Y+3])
                    connection = true;
            }
        }
    }
    //return statement of boolean value
    return connection;
```

My current problem is that it always returns true, no matter what array is put in and I know this may seem like a silly mistake but I really can't find what's wrong. I do have in my main statement before this method is called a check to make sure the input array has a length greater than 4 and the width is greater than 4. This is in java as you already know and answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is you never make connection to false, Just add last else and make connection equal false or make connection to be false by default not true.

```
 public static boolean isConseccutiveFour (int[][] matrix){
        //creates a boolean to give answer later on
        boolean connection = false;
        int[][] consecFour = matrix;
        //incrementing for loops that move through the two arrays by going horizontally then diagonally
        for (int Y = 0; Y < consecFour.length - 3; Y++){
            for(int X= 0; X < consecFour[0].length - 3; X++){
                //if statement used to give the proper constraints for diagonal check 
                if ((consecFour.length - Y < 3) && (consecFour[0].length - X < 3)){
                    if ( consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X + 1][Y + 1] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X+2][Y+2] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X+3][Y+3])
                        connection = true;
                }
                //if statement used to give the proper constraints for diagonal check 
                else if ((consecFour.length - Y < 3) && (consecFour[0].length < 3)){
                    if ( consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X-1][Y-1] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X-2][Y-2] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X-3][Y-3])
                        connection = true;
                }
                //if statement used to give the proper constraints for horizontal check 
                else if (consecFour[0].length - X < 3){
                    if(consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X+1][Y] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X+2][Y] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X+3][Y])
                        connection = true;
                }
                //if statement used to give the proper constraints for vertical check 
                else if (consecFour.length - Y < 3){
                    if ( consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X][Y + 1] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X][Y+2] && consecFour[X][Y] == consecFour[X][Y+3])
                        connection = true;
                }
            }
        }
        //return statement of boolean value
        return connection;
```

Comment: So I did what you said and had created an else statement that makes connection = false; and have the original equation equal false too but now all it does is return false as the answer. even when I have hard coded a connection to equal false.

Comment: My answer was to do one either make it by default false or add an else statement, However I think you should make the condition ((consecFour.length - Y < 3) && (consecFour[0].length - X < 3)) to be ((consecFour.length - 1) - Y <= 3) && ((consecFour[0].length -1) - X <= 3)
Because length starting from 1 and loop starting from 0

Comment: The answer is correct (+1) . I added an explanation that might help.

Answer (score 0):

As user7790438 answered correctly, `connection` is never set to false, so method can only return true. To illustrate it, here is the skeleton of your code :

```
public static boolean isConseccutiveFour (int[][] matrix){

        boolean connection = true;

        for (....){

                if (....){
                        ....
                        connection = true;
                }

                else if (....){
                        ....
                        connection = true;
                }
                else if (....){
                        ....
                        connection = true;
                }

                else if (....){
                        ....
                        connection = true;
                }       
        }

        return connection;
    }
```

Can you see `connection = false1` anywhere ?